# Unable to locate the element for "Connect Instagram" button in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

Need to locate "Connect Instagram" button but none of the xpaths are working.
[image]
I have tried using the below xpaths

```
//button[contains(text(),' Connect ')]

//div/following::button[@class='fsp-button fsp-button--auth fsp-source-auth__el']

//button[@class='fsp-button fsp-button--auth fsp-source-auth__el']

//button[@type='button' and @class='fsp-button fsp-button--auth fsp-source-auth__el']

(//span[@class='fsp-cloudname'])[2]
```

And am getting the "Selenium webdriver exception" error in the console.
[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Am automating using Page object model and below is my code.

```
public Instauploadpage uploadinstaright() throws InterruptedException
{
clickById("eachinstagram_1_1_1");
switchToLastWindow();
Thread.sleep(1000);
WebElement connec = (WebElement)new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("(//span[contains(text(),'Instagram')])[4]")));
connec.click();
return new Instauploadpage(driver);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading your stack trace, it appears your selector is correct, but the button isn't clickable.  Can you add your source code to the post?  An explicit wait with ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable   may solve your problem.

I pulled up the site, see two things:
  1. Looks like you are switching windows too soon (I'm assuming that switchToLastWindow() is a wrapper around get all window handles + switch to last one), that shouldn't happen until you've clicked the button - this seems likely to be the base issue here.
  2. in the interest of code cleanliness: by.cssSelector('#__filestack-picker .fsp-source-auth__wrapper button.fsp-button--auth')  seems a lot easier to read than the xpaths you have.

Comment: @Bowman I have added an explicit wait with ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable but still could'nt  able to locate the element.

Comment: @shanila edited, take another look please.

Comment: @shanila did you get a chance to take a look?

Comment: @Bowman Thanks for your help and I tried as you mentioned but it did'nt worked.